# Eclipse 2020-03: Run a JavaScript program many times to make it work

Tags: javascript, eclipse

From "Eclipse Marketplace" I installed the "Eclipse Web Developer Tools 3.17" plug-in on "Eclipse 2020-03".
Now I can create a "Static Web Project" and run JavaScript programs, but I always have THE SAME problem that I had with "Eclipse Indigo", to run a NEW program I have to launch the NEW program five or six times
(only now everything is noticeably slower).
Sometimes an error window appeared to me, I attach the screenshot.

[Eclipse window error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60vXV.png)

Comment: Any reason why to use a _Static Web Project_ and JSDT instead of [Eclipse Wild Web Developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper)?

Comment: The popup is complaining about something already listening on that port. Do you have something like Tomcat or another web server installed and running outside of Eclipse?